# Exporting AEM experience fragments to Adobe Target automatically every time a related Content Fragment is updated

Tags: adobe, aem, target

I have this unique requirement where each time a particular Content Fragment is updated in AEM, all the Experience Fragments referencing that particular Content Fragment need to be automatically exported to Adobe Target.

Thinking about using SQL2 query to retrieve XFs referencing a particular CF and then incorporating this into a workflow process. Also, wondering if I can leverage aem OOTB workflow process called "Export to Target" in this.
Not really sure of how to call this "Export to Target" process on each Experience Fragment that we need to export to Target or is this possible at all?

Wondering if anyone has ever come across this requirement and succeeded.
Highly appreciate any tips or suggestions in this regard. Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a Content Fragment is created or updated an OSGi event is triggered. All events are logged under http://localhost:4502/system/console/events. You could write a [EventListener or EventHandler](https://www.north-47.com/knowledge-base/event-listener-vs-event-handler-in-aem/), get the path of the event, get the Resource and adapt it to `com.adobe.cq.dam.cfm.ContentFragment`. The topic for these events is "com/day/cq/dam" or in this [constant](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/javadoc/com/day/cq/dam/api/DamEvent.html#EVENT_TOPIC).

From the adapted Class or Resource you can get informations about the model and if it's the model you want to process.

To find all references I would also create an [oak index](https://oakutils.appspot.com/generate/index) and use SQL2 query to find all references.

The query would be something like this:

```
select [jcr:path], [jcr:score], * from [nt:base] as a where contains(*, '"/content/dam/myReferencedModel"')
```

If you have all referencing XF's you can kick off any workflow via [WorkflowService](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/javadoc/com/day/cq/workflow/WorkflowService.html):

```
    @Reference
    private WorkflowService workflowService;

        WorkflowSession wfSession = workflowService.getWorkflowSession(session);
        WorkflowModel wfModel = wfSession.getModel("/var/workflow/models/mymodel");
        WorkflowData wfData = wfSession.newWorkflowData("JCR_PATH", "/payload");
        wfSession.startWorkflow(wfModel, wfData);
```

Comment: I really  appreciate your response which was very helpful.

Just one more thing to clarify regarding the SQL2 query please, suppose I only want to look up for the XFs which have been exported to Target at least once previously. And I can see that such XFs having a new node added under jcr:content as cq:targetMetadata.

So, I modified the  given SQL  like this, but it wouldn't work:
`select [jcr:path], [jcr:score], * from [nt:base] as a where contains(*, '"/content/dam/myReferencedModel"') 
and name(a)="cq:targetMetadata"`

What am I doing wrong in this statement ? 
Many thanks.

Comment: The problem is, that `cq:targetMetadata` is a childnode. The only way is then to do a join: `select * from [nt:base] as a INNER JOIN [nt:base] AS targetChild ON ISCHILDNODE(targetChild, a) where contains(a.*, '"/content/dam/myReferencedModel"') and name(targetChild)="cq:targetMetadata"` 

Please consider accepting my answer :)